# Limiting Wordpress Tag Pages for Tags with more than 10 associated posts

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, add-filter

as the title said, I'm trying to write a custom WordPress filter which limits the creation of Tag pages so that Tag pages are only created if the Tag has more than 10 associated posts. This is because we have so many tags with <10 associated posts, and it's creating a lot of noise.

I've not worked with WordPress for almost 5 years now, so I'm a bit rusty.

Here's what I'm trying, and it's not quite working:

```
<?php
function limit_taxonomies_by_count( $args, $taxonomy, $object_type ) {

  $terms = get_terms('post_tag');

  foreach($term in $terms) {
    if ($term->count < 10) {
      $args = array(
        'public' => false
      )
    }
  }

  return $args
}
add_filter('register_taxonomy_args', 'limit_taxonomies_by_count' );
?>
```

Please let me know what I'm missing!

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `return $args` :P Aside from that, when you say "Tag pages" you mean the Tag archive (eg. `tag.php`)? Or is it something else?

Comment: @cabrerahector Nice catch. Thank you. I mean this template: `tag-{slug}.php`

Comment: Alright, so it is the tag archive. However, this sounds a bit contradictory/illogical to me: "... limits the creation of Tag pages so that Tag pages are only created if the Tag has more than 10 associated posts." If you're creating a tag it doesn't have any posts associated to it because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @cabrerahector Well, we have 200+ tags, but only ~100 have > 10 posts. Quite a few of them have 2-3 posts associated, and we don't want to create pages for those. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I have a different approach in mind that might be a bit less aggresive: how about _hiding_ Tag pages that have less than 10 posts? You could use the `template_redirect` hook to check when a Tag archive page is loaded, then get its posts count and do a redirect to somewhere else (the home page? Another tag?) if it has less than 10 posts.

Comment: @cabrerahector Oh interesting idea. How does that `template_redirect` hook look?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer below. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows to achieve your job done. You can remove those tags link whose associated posts count are less than 10, so visitors can never click on those tags.

```
function modify_term_link_url( $links ) {
    global $post;
    if( !$post ) return $links;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'post_tag' );
    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        return $terms;
    }
    if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $links = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if( $term->count < 10 ){
            $link = '';
        }else{
            $link = get_term_link( $term, 'post_tag' );
            if ( is_wp_error( $link ) ) {
                return $link;
            }
        }
        $links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
    return $links;
}
add_filter( 'term_links-post_tag', 'modify_term_link_url' );
```

Codes goes to your active theme's functions.php

Comment: I believe, using this way, site crawlers could still find that tag page, correct?

Comment: I think if you can do the same logic in tags single page via `template_redirect` hook with checking current query tag and it's count, just redirect to it's previous page. Then everything will be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of preventing the admins / editors from adding new tags, you could just "hide" Tag archive pages that don't meet the criteria (10 or more posts assigned to them). This way, admins/editors can still create / use new tags that might eventually reach 10 or more posts which will then make them visible to visitors.

To do so, you can use the [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) action hook to do *something* before the Tag archive page is loaded on screen (that *something* is explained next), then the [is_tag()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tag/) function to check whether the visitor is trying to access a Tag archive page, and finally the [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) function to do the actual redirection:

```
/**
 * Redirects visitors to the homepage for Tags with
 * less than 10 posts associated to them.
 */
function wp76515_tag_maybe_redirect(){
    // We're viewing a Tag archive page
    if ( is_tag() ) {
        // Get Tag object
        $tag = get_tag(get_queried_object_id());
        // Tag's post count
        $post_count = $tag->count;

        // This tag has less than 10 posts,
        // redirect visitor
        if ( $post_count < 10 ) {
            wp_redirect(
                home_url(), // The URL we're sending the visitor to
                '302' // The HTTP status, 302 = 'Moved Temporarily'
            );
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wp76515_tag_maybe_redirect', 5);
```

You may want to change the redirect code to `301` (Moved Permanently) to remove existing Tag pages with less than 10 posts from Google's index as well.

Comment: Combine this answer with itzmekhoka's below and these barely used tags will be unreachable for both visitors and search engines. At least until they reach 10 posts or more.